# Read a matrix from a file to **a gives me segmentation error

Tags: c

I'm trying to read values from a file to this matrix **a, but I always get `Segmentation fault` because of my `scanf`.
Can you please explain me my error? Thank you

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    int**a;

    FILE * fp;

    int i, j, temp;
    int n = 8;
    fp = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");

    a = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            fscanf(fp, "%d", a[i][j]);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you compile this with warnings, you'll have an idea of at least one of the problems your code have. Always compile with warnings.

Answer (score 5):

You need an ampersand in `fscanf`:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i][j]);
                 ^
```

A second problem that could catch you is that you're using the wrong `sizeof` in the first `malloc`. You want `sizeof(int *)` instead of `sizeof(int)`. A simple rule to avoid such issues is to just use:

```
a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
```

Comment: Not only he's using the wrong formula in malloc, but he's dereferencing an uninitialised pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The first mistake is here: `a = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`.

You have to use `int*` type instead:
`a = malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);`